# Remove rest of string if matches word

Tags: php, smarty

I want to remove rest string where matches for e.g. "exampleword" in smarty.
Or remove last 100 character of string?
Can make with trim function in smarty or some function with PHP?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want? Up until a match, last 100 characters, etc. You could use a regex..

Comment: I want to remove rest of string to the end where matches some word.
Example: String: Hello my example string is here.Test purpose!
If word here is found remove all text to the end, like will be removed .Test purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr()`, example code:

```
echo substr("string of 100 characters ore more...", -5); // re...
echo substr("string of 100 characters ore more...", 0, -5); // string of 100 characters ore mo

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('name', substr('george smith', 0, -3));
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in example #1 for negative start or length in example #2 (depending on which part you want to return) but be sure to check if the  string is actually larger then 100 characters (with `strlen()`) before you do this.

Comment: how to do in smarty ?

Comment: Updated for smarty, im sure you understand how to use smarty templates and how to set them up.